# открытие кода события при клике на кнопке С#

Tags: c#, события

спасайте) в проекте есть несколько одинаковых групп контролов для которых сгенерированы разные события, чтобы не путаться - перенес код для каждой группы из основного файла Form1.cs в файлы OP1.cs (на рисунке зеленая стрелка :) ), OP2.cs и т.д., но теперь при клике, например по кнопке- открывается не тот файл куда я перенес код обработки события (OP1.cs), а Form1.cs где этот код создавался изначально... можно ли как-то исправить эту ситуацию?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такие "одинаковые группы" называются `UserControl`-ы.

Comment: `...теперь при клике, например по кнопке- открывается не тот файл куда я перенес код обработки события...` `...можно ли как-то исправить эту ситуацию?` - нельзя, редактор студии предполагает наличие одного код-бихайнд файла. Хотя, надо признать, ваша мысль движется в правильном направлении, логику нужно отделять от виз. интерфейса в отдельные класс(ы). Подписывание на события лучше прописывать вручную в конструкторе формы. Создаете класс `MainViewModel` с какой-то логикой, а чтоб вызвать по клику метод из этого класса в конструкторе пишете `button1.Click += (s, e) => mainViewModel.Method1();`